# How do I fetch value of category from database using posted numeric id

Tags: php

First of all, forgive me for being very green with PHP. I am a recruiter for dentists and 
I have a form that I have my candidates fill out online.

I created 4 mysql tables that hold information for discipline, type buyer, transition time and graduation year. This allows me to change options 1 time rather than doing this on multiple pages on my website.

You can see the form at http://www.missouridentalpracticeforsale.com/indexnewbjs.php

When the form is submitted, I have it working correctly to dump in the database into the database table I created.  However, I have an email that is sent to me every time I get a new lead and for the fields that have been created in these tables, I am only getting the ID value and I need to get the content associated with the ID..

Ex.  instead of getting dentist for discipline, I get the value of 1
     Instead of getting orthodontist buyer for type of buyer I get #3

Here is my code for both the index page and the form submittal page

----------small portion of code for 2 fields Discipline and Type Buyer--------------

```
<tr>
<td>Discipline:</td>
<td><select name="disc" class="tableappointdata" id="disc">
<?php $discpfs_sql = 'SELECT id, disc FROM discpfs WHERE id >= 0'; $discpfs_res =       sql_query($discpfs_sql,$leads_db); while($discpfs = mysql_fetch_array($discpfs_res)){ echo '<option value="' . $discpfs['id'] . '">' . $discpfs['disc'] . '</option>'; } ?>
                      </select>                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Type Buyer:</td>
                      <td><select name="typebuy" class="tableappointdata" id="typebuy">
                        <?php $typebuy_sql = 'SELECT id, typebuy FROM typebuy WHERE id >= 0'; $typebuy_res = mysql_query($typebuy_sql,$leads_db); while($typebuy = mysql_fetch_array($typebuy_res)){ echo '<option value="' . $typebuy['id'] . '">' . $typebuy['typebuy'] . '</option>'; } ?>
                      </select>                      </td>
                    </tr>

-------------------------------Form Submittal Code------------------------------------

            $msg  .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '<br   />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Discipline: ' . $_POST ['disc']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Type Buyer: ' . $_POST['typebuy']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Transition Time: ' . $_POST['transtime']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Practice Type Desired: ' . $_POST['desire']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Practice Size Wanted: ' . $_POST['practsize']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Number of Ops: ' . $_POST['numberops']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Graduation Year: ' . $_POST['grad']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'City: ' . $_POST['city']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'State: ' . $_POST['state']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
        $msg  .= 'Zip: ' . $_POST['zip']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
```

I know this is probably a very easy fix, but I am going crazy trying to figure out how I get the words to show up and not the corresponding ID numbers from the table in my email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the error.

```
echo '<option value="' . $discpfs['id'] . '">' . $discpfs['disc'] . '</option>';
```

You are displaying the actual content on the select option, but what is sent by the form's POST method is the "value" field, that is, the $discpfs['id'].

You have 2 options them, if you are not using the id after submitting the form you can send the actual content on the "value" field

```
echo '<option value="' . $discpfs['disc'] . '">' . $discpfs['disc'] . '</option>';
```

but if you use the id, you can make another query using the id and build your string $msg using the value retrieved by the query.

Use a query like this:

```
$discpfs_sql = 'SELECT id, disc FROM discpfs WHERE id ='. $_POST['disc'];
```

Comment: @meda, the name field of the select is disc, that's why I kept it $_POST['disc'].

Comment: sorry I rolled back the edit, you still got my vote ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead.

```
    $disc_id=$_POST ['disc'];
    $discpfs_sql = mysql_query("SELECT disc FROM discpfs WHERE id = '$disc_id'");
    $disc=mysql_fetch_array($discpfs_sql);
    $type_id=$_POST ['typebuy'];
    $typebuy_sql = mysql_query("SELECT typebuy FROM typebuy WHERE id = '$type_id'");
    $typebuy=mysql_fetch_array($typebuy_sql);
    $msg  .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . '<br   />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Discipline: ' . $disc['disc']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Type Buyer: ' . $typebuy['typebuy']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Transition Time: ' . $_POST['transtime']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Practice Type Desired: ' . $_POST['desire']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Practice Size Wanted: ' . $_POST['practsize']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Number of Ops: ' . $_POST['numberops']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Graduation Year: ' . $_POST['grad']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'City: ' . $_POST['city']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'State: ' . $_POST['state']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
    $msg  .= 'Zip: ' . $_POST['zip']  . '<br />' . "\r\n";
```